# virtualenvwrapper error - all mkvirtualenv already exists

Tags: virtualenvwrapper

So I am new in Python. I install the latest Python 3.6.2 and installed virtualenvwrapper via

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

but the problem is whenever I run the command mkvirtualenv it throws me an error about the virtualenv already exists, whereas I have not created any virtual environment yet.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXYsP.png)

Comment: This issue (spaces in paths) has now been fixed.

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win/issues/85

Hi!

I also encountered this problem earlier. It seems like there's a problem with the new version of `virtualenvwrapper-win`.
What I did to resolve this issue was I uninstalled the package and then installed the previous version.

Here are the pip commands for doing so:

```
pip uninstall virtualenvwrapper-win
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win==1.2.0
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks ! The issue is now closed, they have a fix which will be released with v1.2.3.

Comment: Glad to be of help. :)

Comment: This issues, along with a number of other spaces in paths/virtualenv names, have now been fixed.